# Delete dialog box not showing delete and cancel

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react admin code delete dialog box is not showing **delete / cancel** after clicking **delete**. Its showing

```
Ra.action.cancel ra.action.delete
```

In the code I have imported ra-custom-confirm
[React admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) ver is *3.8.1* in **package.json**.

Answer (score 0):

What you see are translation identifiers, which are normally converted to text by the internationalization (i18n) system of React-admin.

If you havent't tweaked the i18nProvider in your Admin, you may have imported two conflicting versions of the same react-admin package (probably `ra-core`). Check your `yarn.lock` or `packages-lock.json` for duplicate versions of `ra-*` packages.